# ddply bug? (Adding lm residuals computed within groups back to the original data frame)

Tags: r, plyr, lm

I have a data frame with a factor (grpfactor). My goal is to compute residuals form fitting an lm model separately within each group, and store them in the original data frame.

The model needs to be specified at run-time (i.e., cannot be a fixed string).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205656/run-regression-by-groups-and-assign-the-fitted-values-and-or-residuals-back-into)

```
  ddply(d,.(g1,g2),transform,z= predict(lm(y ~ x)))
```

It seems to work with a statically specified formula, but if I put the code inside a function and use a string variable instead of a string literal (constant), it fails -- why??

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20), 
            y = rnorm(20), 
            g1 = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10)), 
            g2 = rep(c(rep('c', 5), rep('d', 5)), 2))


myfunc = function(d) {
xx = "y ~ x"
retval = ddply(d,.(g1,g2),transform,z= predict(lm(as.formula(xx))))
return(retval)
}

# This fails:
d.new = myfunc(d)

# With the error:
#Error: error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a 
#method for function 'predict': Error in as.formula(xx) : object 'xx' not 
#found 


# But this works, because it's not encased in a function:
xx = "y ~ x"
retval = ddply(d,.(g1,g2),transform,z= predict(lm(as.formula(xx))))

#Now, with the variable "xx" defined two lines above this line, 
#the following will actually work now:
d.new = myfunc(d)

#But if we do this, it will fail again:
rm(xx)
d.new = myfunc(d)

#ddply works inside a function, but only with a model specified 
#as a literal string:
myfunc2 = function(d) {
retval = ddply(d,.(g1,g2),transform,z= predict(lm(formula=as.formula("y ~ x"))))
return(retval)
}
d.new2 = myfunc2(d)
```

As an aside, without as.formula, myfunc2 fails with the error:

```
#Error: error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method 
#for function 'predict': Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' 
#not found
```

But the same code works without as.formula if it's not in a function.

What is going on?

Edit: ok, here's where it gets really crazy: this works ( the difference is, I am defining the model in the parent environment using <<- )

```
 myfunc3 = function(d) {
 xx <<- "y ~ x"
 retval = ddply(d,.(g1,g2),transform,z= predict(lm(as.formula(xx))))
 return(retval)
 }
 myfunc3(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error :

```
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Because when `ddply` try to resolve `t` in the local environment before the global environment. Indeed, it found the transpose function (closure) `t` and not your global variable t.
You need just to change to something other R built-in functions ( t,c,..). For example this will work:

```
xx <- "y ~ x"
```

A complete example :

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20), 
                y = rnorm(20), 
                g1 = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10)), 
                g2 = rep(c(rep('c', 5), rep('d', 5)), 2))
xx <- "y ~ x"
ddply(d,.(g1,g2),transform,z= predict(lm(as.formula(xx))))

#            x           y g1 g2           z
# 1 -0.2066509 -0.74159051  a  c -0.21886198
# 2 -0.9801753  1.38958373  a  c  0.62214098
# 3 -0.4626821  0.48195967  a  c  0.05950415
# 4  1.2255134 -1.72809777  a  c -1.77596158
# 5 -1.0922717  0.02898265  a  c  0.74401621
# 6 -1.4379229  0.96377879  a  d  0.18312800
```

Comment: Looks like I marked it answered too soon!  As soon as I put ddply inside a function, it no longer works.  I'm editing the original question with a better toy example to demonstrate the error.

Comment: @Dimitri this is a bug in `ddply`. You can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149150/ddply-run-in-a-function-looks-in-the-environment-outside-the-function) for more details